# getting id from inside controller rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails so I don't know the correct terminology.
I'm trying to get an id of a community from my subscription controller but I'm getting the error `undefined method 'community_id' for nil:NilClass`

my `SubscriptionController.rb`:

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @subscription = Subscription.new(subscription_params)
        @subscription.account_id = current_account.id
        @subscription.save
        redirect_to community_path(@subcription.community_id)   //error here
        redirect_to community_path(params[:community_id])   // also error below
        end
    end
    
    def subscription_params
        params.require(:subscription).permit(:community_id)
end
```

error from 2nd line try: `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"communities", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id]`.

The subscription is saving into the db. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: first error, let's fix the typo `@subcription` missing `s`; second error, it should be `params[:subscription][:community_id]`; `params` is like a hash, you can always inspect it and see if something is missing. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html

Comment: Thanks for your help @Alex. How do you inspect things? I can't find a good intellisense extension for vscode

Comment: `puts params.inspect` then look in the console. also in the logs where it says `Parameters: `, that's what you're getting in `params`

Comment: @Alex A better idea is to actually dedugging tool such as `debug`, `byebug` or `pry` to set a breakpoint and step into the code.  `debug` in included by default in the Rails 7 gemfile and `byebug` in previous versions. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Whle there probally is a tool withing VSCode to integrate with the debug gem you should probally learn the good old fashioned way by using a terminal first so that you're not completely reliant on an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You're making three common rookie misstakes here:

- You're assuming that the `community_id` passed by the user is actually valid and corresponds with an existing record. Never trust user input.
- You're assuming that creating the record will always succeed. It won't - and you should always code defensively to handle that condition. For example if the user double clicks the button the second request should fail as it would lead to a duplicate record.
- You're redirecting twice. Each request can only have one response and what you would be doing is just overwriting the `LOCATION` header unless Rails prevented you from doing it with a double render error.

Instead I would do this as a [nested route](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources):

```ruby
# config/routes.rb
resources :communities do
  resources :subscriptions, only: [:create]
end
```

```ruby
class Account < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subscriptions

  # ...
end
```

```ruby
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_community, only: [:create]

  # POST /communities/1/subscriptions
  def create
    # I'm assuming that you are ensuring the account is actually signed in your ApplicationController
    # note that you don't need to use strong parameters here as you're not mass assigning any parameters
    @subscription = current_account.subscriptions.new(
      community: @community
    )
    # Ensure that the user is notified if creating the record fails.
    if @subscription.save
      redirect_to @community,
        success: 'You are now subscribed.'
    else 
      # @todo provide a more specific failure reason
      redirect_to @community, 
        error: 'Could not create subscription. Please try again later.' 
    end
  end

  private

  def set_community
    # this will bail early and return a 404 response if an invalid id is passed. 
    @community = Community.find(params[:community_id])
  end
end
```

```ruby
# app/views/communities/show.html.erb
<%= button_to "Subscribe", [@community, :subscriptions], method: :post %>
```

This places the `community_id` parameter as part of the URL itself and is how you RESTfully model relations between resources. The relation is explicit instead of tucked away into the request body. If you're ever passing record ids as hidden inputs you're most likely doing it wrong.